Problem with matplotlib FuncAnimation and numpy arrays
I'm making a simple bouncing ball simulation in python with animation using matplotlib FuncAnimation but I've been coming across a lot of problems:
When I debug for some reason all my numpy arrays are full and have all the values from the previous run and then when I look at the graph it starts spasming and creating weird patterns.
When I run it normally it works perfectly until the first bounce: after the first bounce for some reason it starts randomly spasming.
I've been battling with this for about a long time please help if you can.
The code is annotated so hopefully that helps, you'll want to focus on my UpdateFrame function in line 11 and calling the FuncAnimation in line 90:
#Importing libraries
import matplotlib as mpl #Matplotlib for graphing
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #Function for actually plotting the graphs
import numpy as np #Useful for arrays
import math #For all the trigonometric calculations
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator #Useful for setting fixed axes scales
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation #Used for animating the plot
from tkinter import * #Used for GUI


def update_frame(frame):
    #Update_frame will be passed to the animation function because it needs a function that will return a new line for each frame
    #The way FuncAnimation handles the local variables in the update frame function is strange so I have to move most variables to global scope
    global v_x, v_y, x_pos, y_pos, N_bounce, bounce_flag
    i = frame 
    try: #Added try if i is out of range meaning the simulation stopped
        if N_bounce > N:
            return line, ball,
        #np.append is formatted like array = np.append(array, item you want to add to array) and it returns a new array with the item in it.
        #np arrays are used because it is a lot more compatable with matplotlib graphs
#A B C D E F all for debugging
        a = y_pos[i]
        b = v_y[i]
        x_pos = np.append(x_pos, x_pos[i] + (v_x * dt))  #Find next x coordinate and append it
        y_pos = np.append(y_pos, y_pos[i] + (v_y[i] * dt)) #Find next y coordinate and append it
        v_y = np.append(v_y, v_y[i] - (g * dt)) #Calculate new y velocity
        c = y_pos[i+1]
        d = v_y[i+1]
        if y_pos[i+1] < 0 and v_y[i+1] < 0 and bounce_flag == False: #A bounce condition for the animation if y drops below zero/hits the ground
            y_pos[i+1] = 0 #Puts ball at ground level instead of below
            v_y[i+1] = -v_y[i+1] * C #Reverses y velocity
            e = y_pos[i+1]
            f = v_y[i+1]
            N_bounce += 1
            bounce_flag = True #This will make sure the ball only bounces once when it hits the ground
            
        if v_y[i+1] < 0:
            bounce_flag = False #Resets bounce flag as it will only bounce when velocity is negative
        line.set_data(x_pos,y_pos) #Update the data of the line
        ball.set_data([x_pos[i+1]], [y_pos[i+1]]) #Update position of ball to last position on trajectory animation
        return line, ball, #Return the line and ball to the FuncAnimation function
    except IndexError:
        return line, ball,


def init_func(): 
    #This function is passed to the Func Animation function to initialise the graph
    global line, ax, ball
    ax.set_title('Projectile Simulation, T = '+ str(T) + 's')
    ax.set_xlabel('x /m')
    ax.set_ylabel('y /m')
    ax.grid()
    line, = ax.plot(x_pos,y_pos, color = 'blue', label = 'No air resistance')
    ball, = ax.plot([x_pos[-1]], [y_pos[-1]], color = 'blue', marker = 'o', markersize = 5)


#Making a graph function so that it can be called easily with GUI
def graph(theta, u, h):
    global v_x, v_y, x_pos, y_pos, g, dt, fig, ax, T, N_bounce, bounce_flag
    #theta = launch angle from horizontal in degrees
    #g = strength of gravity in m/s^2
    #u = launch speed in m/s
    #h = launch height in m
    N_bounce = 0 #Number of bounces
    dt = 0.005 #time step in s
    theta = math.radians(theta) #turns theta into radians for calculations

    u_x = u * math.cos(theta) # initial x velocity
    u_y = u * math.sin(theta) # initial y velocity

    v_x = u_x # since x velocity doesn't change this is not an array
    v_y = np.array([u_y]) # Velocity array

    x_pos = np.array([0.0]) # array of x positions relative to origin during flight /m
    y_pos = np.array([float(h)]) # array of y positions relative to origin during flight /m
    
    highest_y = (u_y**2)/(2*g) + h 
    if C != 1:
        T = 2*((2*highest_y/g)**(1/2))*((1/(1-C))-0.5) #Finding out how long until the ball stops bouncing
    else:
        T = 2*((2*highest_y/g)**(1/2))*((1/(1-0.9))-0.5)


    last_frame = int((T//dt) + 1)*10#Calculates the number of frames needed, adding 1 to ensure it rounds up
    highest_x = T * v_x #Calculating the highest x for accurate scale
    #Finding the apogee using v**2 = u**2 - 2gs 
    # u**2/2g = s
    fig, ax = plt.subplots() #Initialises the axes and figure
    bounce_flag = False #This will be used in the animation function
    ani = FuncAnimation(fig, func= update_frame, frames = range(last_frame),init_func=init_func(),blit = True, interval = 3, repeat = False) #Makes the animation
    plt.axis([0,(highest_x//1)+1,0,(highest_y//1)+1]) #Setting axis range
    plt.legend()
    plt.show() #Shows the graph and animation

root = Tk() #Intialising window

theta_entry = Entry(root, width = 50) #Input box for angle
g_entry = Entry(root, width=50) #Input box for gravity
u_entry = Entry(root, width=50) #Input box for initial speed
h_entry = Entry(root, width=50) #Input box for height
N_entry = Entry(root, width=50) #Input box for number of bounces
C_entry = Entry(root, width=50) #Input box for C

def clicked(): #Function for if the enter_button is clicked
    global g, C, N #Makes g global for other variables
    theta = theta_entry.get() #Gets the values from each text box
    g = g_entry.get()
    u = u_entry.get()
    h = h_entry.get()
    N = N_entry.get()
    C = C_entry.get()
    if len(theta) != 0 and len(g) != 0 and len(u) != 0 and len(h) != 0 and len(N) != 0 and len(C) != 0: #Ensures they are not empty
        try: #Tries to convert the values into floats
            theta = float(theta)
            g = float(g)
            u = float(u)
            h = float(h)
            N = int(N)
            C = float(C)
            if g > 0 and u >= 0 and h >= 0 and theta >= -90 and theta <= 90 and N >= 0 and C <= 1 and C >= 0: #Checks if data is valid
                graph(theta,u,h) #Outputs the graph
            else: #Tells the user to make sure all data is valid
                error_label.config(text = 'Ensure g > 0, u >= 0, h >= 0, -90 <= theta <= 90, N >= 0, and 0 <= C <= 1')
        
        except ValueError: #If values can't be converted into floats, tell the user to make sure all data is numerical
            error_label.config(text = 'Ensure all data is numerical')
    
    else: #If the text box is empty is enters an error message
        error_label.config(text = 'Ensure all data is filled')


enter_button = Button(root,text = 'Finalise data', command= clicked) #Create the labels
theta_label = Label(root, text= 'Enter the launch angle from the horizontal in degrees: ') 
g_label = Label(root, text= 'Enter the strength of gravity in m/s^2: ')
u_label = Label(root, text= 'Enter the launch speed in m/s: ')
h_label = Label(root, text='Enter the launch height in m: ')
N_label = Label(root, text='Enter the number of bounces: ')
C_label = Label(root, text='Enter the coefficient of restitution: ')
error_label = Label(root, text= 'Ensure all data is correct')


theta_label.pack() #Add all the buttons and labels and entry boxes in the correct order
theta_entry.pack()
g_label.pack()
g_entry.pack()
u_label.pack()
u_entry.pack()
h_label.pack()
h_entry.pack()
N_label.pack()
N_entry.pack()
C_label.pack()
C_entry.pack()
enter_button.pack()

root.mainloop() #Display window and start mainloop

When I debug it it also randomly skips frames when I step through i.e: the frame value that is passed to the function in funcAnimation randomly jumps from 1 to 647.
